# How to convert font file type pfm to ttf for web

Tags: html, ms-word, fckeditor

I using fckeditor in my website to add hindi font(MENKA) from ms word by copy paste but it do not paste fonts in proper format.The fonts are in hindi menka fonts which looks perfect in ms word but not in fckeditor .The reason it look perfect in word is the fonts file available in extention of pfm in controlpanel/fonts/.and web cant show perfect result because web do not allow pfm font file thats why i need to convert pfm to ttf.I am thinking if i found ttf extention MENKA font file my problem may be solved.any one know how to onert pfm to ttf or from where i can found MENKA ttf.thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I usually search for a tool like the following:
https://onlinefontconverter.com/

Comment: I already used given link convertor but it shows error Failed to convert MENKA1.PFM . i find many tools but most of them are allow convertion from pbf to ttf and etc.

Comment: Is it possible your original file is corrupted or non standard in some way?

Comment: I don't know, but I have seen stranger things. If you had an alternate source for the file it would be worth a try.

Comment: if i found direct MENKA font file in .ttf than too its better to solve this issue any know where i can find MENKA ttf file .